Which ITR to file for deduction u/s 194JB
Which ITR to file for deduction u/s 194JB
Which ITR to file for deduction u/s 194JB
I've received remuneration for writing articles in tech blogging site, in the form-16 it was mentioned 194 J(B)
I've filed a return with ITR-1, but i've received a below notice:

Important ‐ Rectify the defect in your Return of Income

You have filed your income-tax return in form ITR-1. As per TDS details in your Form 26AS, taxes have been deducted under sections
194IA/194IC/194M/194S/194C/194B/194BB/194BA, etc. of the Income-tax Act, 1961. These sections are 
reflected as (4IA/4IC/94M/94S/94C/94B/4BB/4BA) in Form 26AS. These sections imply heads of income for which
form no. ITR-1 is not the appropriate form. Thus, the required schedules for reporting incomes pertaining 
to said TDS sections are not present in your return of income filed in form no. ITR-1.

What should i do now ?
